# How to set the command history in a Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, sh

I'm running the docker container locally to troubleshoot its state.  I don't always want to execute the `RUN`/`ENTRYPOINT`, I often want to get into the running container, do some things, and then run the `RUN`/`ENTRYPOINT`.

It would be super convenient to have the `RUN`/`ENTRYPOINT` available after I `docker run bash` by just pressing the up key.  So I thought it would be nice if I could modify the history with `history -s ...` in the `Dockerfile`.  That way, as soon as I `docker run bash`, I can just press up and have the `RUN`/`ENTRYPOINT` available.

When I put this in the docker file, I got this error:

```
 /bin/sh: 1: history: not found
```

Is there a way to set the bash history in a Dockerfile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the error because `RUN` commands run in `/bin/sh`, which has no `history` command available.

To make this work, you need to run an interactive bash shell during the build, so it will store your history entry.

```sh
RUN bash -ic 'history -s foobar'
```

That should leave behind a history file with `foobar` as its most recent (and probably only) entry.

You will see an error during build about ioctl... that is normal, because interactive bash expects to find a terminal, and there won't be one. But it should still work fine.

> bash: cannot set terminal process group (1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
>   bash: no job control in this shell

Note that this will be stored for the user you run the command as. If your image switches to a non-root user with the `USER` statement, you should put this after the `USER` line so it is stored in the user that your image runs as.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried this and when I pressed up, the history was not there.  This was the output of `history` was blank.

Comment: @DanielKaplan What dockerfile are you using? I build a simple dockerfile with `FROM ubuntu:latest` and that one RUN command. Ran it as `docker run -it myimage bash` and history was working in my test.

Comment: My issue was I had `RUN bash -ic 'history -s foobar &', I need to escape the & like this: `RUN bash -ic 'history -s foobar \&' and it worked.  Thanks

Comment: @DanielKaplan Ah ok. The `&` seems unnecessary, but I'm glad you solved it.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Oh! I see, I thought you were trying to background the `history` command, misunderstood.